# RFECV does not return same features for same data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe X which is comprised of 60 features and ~ 450k outcomes.   My response variable y is categorical (survival, no survival).

I would like to use RFECV to reduce the number of significant features for my estimator (right now, logistic regression) on Xtrain, which I would like to score of accuracy under an ROC Curve.  "Features Selected" is a list of all features.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
import sklearn.linear_model as lm

#  Create train and test datasets to evaluate each model
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X,y,train_size = 0.70)
# Use RFECV to reduce features

#  Create a logistic regression estimator 
logreg = lm.LogisticRegression()

# Use RFECV to pick best features, using Stratified Kfold
rfecv =   RFECV(estimator=logreg, cv=StratifiedKFold(ytrain, 10), scoring='roc_auc')

# Fit the features to the response variable
X_new = rfecv.fit_transform(Xtrain[features_selected], ytrain)
```

I have a few questions:

a) X_new returns different features when run on separate occasions (one time it returned 5 features, another run it returned 9.  One is not a subset of the other).  Why would this be?

b) Does this imply an unstable solution?  While using the same seed for StratifiedKFold should solve this problem, does this mean I need to reconsider the approach in totality?

c) IN general, how do I approach tuning?  e.g., features are selected BEFORE tuning in my current implementation.   Would tuning affect the significance of certain features?   Or should I tune simultaneously?

Comment: a & b) I would bet that if you use LeaveOneOut CV, you will get a more stable result c) IMO try both and see how it affects CV score. As a general comment, there are other ways to perform feature selection that are worth looking into. For example, check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230019/how-can-we-get-to-know-the-selected-and-omitted-features-columns-names-heade/29230723#29230723

Comment: @Ryan - thanks for the help.   I'll check LOOCV.   Regarding your answer to question 29230019, what would you suggest if Feature Importance is not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is **randomly** partitioned into k equal size sub-samples. Therefore, it's not surprising to get different results every time you execute the algorithm. [Source](https://www.openml.org/a/estimation-procedures/1)

There is an approach, so-called **Pearson's correlation coefficient**. By using this method, you can calculate the a correlation coefficient between each two features, and aim for removing features with a high correlation. This method could be considered as a stable solution to such a problem. [Source](https://www.openml.org/a/evaluation-measures/correlation-coefficient)