# Identify important features in classification task

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have several vectors such as:

```
s1:1;s2:1;s3:0;s4:0;s5:0;s6:0;s7:0;s8:1;s9:0;s10:0;s11:1;s12:0;s13:0;s14:0;s15:0;p:1
s1:1;s2:1;s3:0;s4:0;s5:0;s6:0;s7:0;s8:1;s9:0;s10:1;s11:0;s12:0;s13:0;s14:0;s15:0;p:0
s1:1;s2:1;s3:0;s4:0;s5:0;s6:0;s7:0;s8:1;s9:1;s10:0;s11:0;s12:0;s13:0;s14:0;s15:0;p:0
s1:1;s2:1;s3:0;s4:0;s5:0;s6:0;s7:1;s8:0;s9:0;s10:0;s11:0;s12:0;s13:0;s14:0;s15:1;p:1
```

According to the last entry (p) I want to determine, which of the components s1 ... s15 are most important to determine the outcome of p.

I search a machine learning algorithm that can 'understand' the correlation between several variables. If for example `s2 = s4 = 1 = p` does always hold, the algorithm should give me something like: `s2 = 1.0, s4 = 1.0` . Variables that are less important to determine the outcome of p should have a value between 0.0 and 1.0

My Code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
y = y[1:50]
X = X[1:50]
target_names = iris.target_names

pca = PCA(n_components=4)

X_r = pca.fit(X).transform(X)

plt.figure()
for c, i, target_name in zip("rgb", [0, 1, 2], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_r[y == i, 0], X_r[y == i, 1], c=c, label=target_name)
plt.legend()
plt.title('PCA of IRIS dataset')

plt.show()

# Matlab code to achieve what I want. See also:
# http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html
# [a,b,c]= pca(X);
# c
```

Comment: "I small snippet of" **your** "code would be most helpful". What have you tried so far? Don't you think Cross Validated is a better place for this question? SO is for people who tried something that failed to work properly, not for "make my work from scratch" type of people.

Comment: Have you heard of principal component analysis?

Comment: I heard of PCA and I looked into this tutorial: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html a small hint on how to do this according to the code that can be found there would also help.

Comment: Better fit would be LDA since you have the class information in your data. Try it yourself don't ask for the code. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html

Comment: Thank you Riyaz, I will check it out.

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad and find the tone of comments overly harsh. The title is certainly too broad, but as I read the actual question now, it seems perfectly fine to me. @user2177047 this link may prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230019/how-can-we-get-to-know-the-selected-and-omitted-features-columns-names-heade/29230723#29230723 Also, if you're interested in identifying the importances of individual features, I don't think PCA is the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I am just having a look at your code...

Comment: Wow thank you again Ryan. This helped me a lot and gave me exactly what I needed. I would post my solution now but the question is still on hold :) Well never mind. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution based on Ryan's comment and the link to his code (above):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

# Build a forest and compute the feature importances
forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250,
                              random_state=0)

X = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]])
y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
forest.fit(X, y)

#array with importances of each feature
importances = forest.feature_importances_

print importances
```

Comment: (+1) for the effort and I removed my downvote from your question, though you should've started with something like this. Anyway, I hope you understand how tree ensembles work. I recommend you read this short thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82503/can-random-forest-methodology-be-applied-to-linear-regressions (note that Random Forests are very similar to Extra Random Forests)

Comment: Good that the question is now in accordance to the community guidelines. Thanks for the link. I'll have a look at it.